# Journal title wont display in reference list

Tags: bibliographies

Im using a .bib file to store all my references and am using package ieeetr to display the references. However the journal title wont display in the references. I have even downloaded the .sty file available [here](https://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs_doc/aas_macros.sty). This is the code I am using.

```
\usepackage{tabularx} % extra features for tabular environment
\usepackage{amsmath}  % improve math presentation
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr} 
\usepackage{aas_macros}
\usepackage{siunitx} %for degree symbol

\usepackage[margin=1in,letterpaper]{geometry} % decreases margins
```

This is the entry in my .bib file

```
@ARTICLE{blackhole,
       author = {{Ghez}, A.~M. and {Klein}, B.~L. and {Morris}, M. and {Becklin}, E.~E.},
        title = "{High Proper-Motion Stars in the Vicinity of Sagittarius A*: Evidence for a Supermassive Black Hole at the Center of Our Galaxy}",
      journal = {\apj},
     keywords = {BLACK HOLE PHYSICS, GALAXY: CENTER, GALAXY: KINEMATICS AND DYNAMICS, INFRARED: STARS, STARS: KINEMATICS, TECHNIQUES: IMAGE PROCESSING, Black Hole Physics, Galaxy: Center, Galaxy: Kinematics and Dynamics, Infrared: Stars, Stars: Kinematics, Techniques: Image Processing, Astrophysics},
         year = 1998,
        month = dec,
       volume = {509},
       number = {2},
        pages = {678-686},
          doi = {10.1086/306528},
archivePrefix = {arXiv},
       eprint = {astro-ph/9807210},
 primaryClass = {astro-ph},
       adsurl = {https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1998ApJ...509..678G},
      adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System}
}
```

And this is what the reference looks like -

A. M. Ghez, B. L. Klein, M. Morris, and E. E. Becklin, “High Proper-Motion Stars in the
Vicinity of Sagittarius A*: Evidence for a Supermassive Black Hole at the Center of Our
Galaxy,” ApJ, vol. 509, pp. 678–686, Dec. 1998.

It keeps abbreviating Astrophysical Journal and I cant figure out why. Can someone help me?

Comment: Have you tried replacing `journal = {\apj},` with `journal = apj`? I you keep getting the same result, it must be because the `ieeetr` bib style has been set up to expand `\apj` to, you guessed it, `ApJ`.

Comment: In `aas_macros.sty` you find `\def\apj{\ref@jnl{ApJ}}`, and TeX follows instructions, so it typesets “ApJ”. I'm not sure why you're using `\apj` if you want “Astrophysical Journal”.

Comment: @Mico Hi, yes I have tried replacing `journal = {\apj}` with `journal = apj` and it didnt change anything

Comment: @egreg When I use `journal = {ApJ}` it simply prints the letters in italics. Can you help me further?

Comment: Type in the full name